# YA thriller with a character named Mango

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

In the 2000's as a teenager/preteen maybe I read a thriller about a girl who meets someone identical to her, named Mango. I can't remember much else except that I think they were clones and there is someone pursuing them, and the main girl lives at home with who she thought were her parents.

It's not *Replica* or *Double Identity*. The Mango character is "cool" and there is a sinister character pursuing them.

I think in the story the main girl has issues with her memory and can't remember her life, due to an accident, but her parents  her in on her life. The rest of the details are very vague but they keep a close watch on her.

edit- quite possibly an Australian YA book.

Comment: It looks like [Twitter user TeaCell](https://mobile.twitter.com/_Tahlia_/status/1317454977338462209) and [Tumblr user ryttu3k](https://ryttu3k.tumblr.com/post/83801325243/i-hate-it-when-a-novel-pops-into-your-head-and-is) are looking for the same book. Can you look at these threads and see if you remember any more details?

Comment: It's exactly the book TeaCell is talking about on Twitter! Unfortunately I don't remember any more details, except for that there is something about clones in the end. I didn't realise it was an Australian book but that makes sense since I'm Australian as well.